# PySpark: Use TransformedDStream in Barplot

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I consume from Kafak some events, the data looks like the following:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-12-21 21:52:58
-------------------------------------------
150.0

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-12-21 21:53:00
-------------------------------------------
155.0

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-12-21 21:53:02
-------------------------------------------
160.0
```

My code producing that logs looks like the following:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName='Python Streaming')

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1) 
ssc.checkpoint("abc")
# create the stream
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, \
          'XXXX:YYYY', \
          'streaming-consumer', \
          {'topic':1})

windows=kvs.window(10,2).map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1])['val'])

#here the avgs are created    
avg=windows.map(lambda x:(x,1)).reduce(lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0],x[1]+y[1])).map(lambda x:x[0]/x[1])

#creates the log shown above
avg.pprint()
```

Now, I want to have a tiny (live) barplot visualization. I tried something like this by adding the following two lines after `avg=windows.map(lambda x:(x,1)).reduce(lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0],x[1]+y[1])).map(lambda x:x[0]/x[1])` - however, it didn't work (the plot is not updating):

```
avg.foreachRDD(lambda x:myList.append(x.collect()))

sns.barplot(x=myList[-1])
```

What is the easiest approach to visualize such a stream data?

I am working with juypiter notebook and python3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this data flow -

Source Kafka topic -> spark streaming consumer ->  some database(like -influx db ) -> graphana

Just jupyter notebook and python is not enough for implementation of realtime visualisation for spark streaming